# Regex Invalid Escape Sequence on Split String

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm attempting to make my String array split on whitespace or any punctuation besides the dash character. This is my attempt:

```
String[] temp = lowerCased.split("\p{Blank}\\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]");
```

I'm getting the Invalid Escape Sequence and I figure it has to do with Java's need for a double backslash, but I can't pinpoint where exactly it's going wrong. I put it into one of the Regex emulation programs and it seemed to get the result I was going for.

Comment: The first backslash is not escaped, it should be. There are three backslashes in the middle when two backslashes will do. Also you have a hanging `]`.

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes are not escaped properly, try this. There is also a left square bracket missing at the beginning.

```
String[] temp = "".split("[\\p{Blank}\\\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]");
```